# Articles in "OK Google, go back to the earbud drawing board"

Tags: articles

Here is the title of a (news-)article:

> Pixel Buds review: OK Google, go back to **the earbud drawing board**

Can anybody, please, explain why `the` is used before `earbud drawing board`.

Here is how I understand the situation.

In the past, there were several drawing boards where they discussed the design of earbuds, and, what is more important, in the future they can discuss buds' design by a lot of other drawing boards (not necessary the same one that they used to discuss the design first time). So, why does the author of the article want them to discuss the design by that specific drawing board?

I know that I am wrong somewhere, please, correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go back to the drawing board

is a [well documented phrase](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-back-to-the-drawing-board).

"The" does not indicate a specific drawing board, or even an actual drawing board, because the phrase can be a metaphor for starting over.

A similar phrase is

> Go back to square one.

Comment: But what does 'earbud' function in "go back to the *earbud* drawing board"?

Comment: @dan I [googled the question title](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/pixel-buds-review-ok-google-go-back-to-the-earbud-drawing-board/) to get the context. Evidently the earbud is a type of earphone, not a type of drawing board. Just as an "earbud drawer" would be a place where earbuds are kept, not a type of drawer ;)